# CSS3 tooltip background

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap on my website but I don't like the css on the tooltip, so I override him with Menu-cool CSS3 Tootips.

The thing is in the background of the tooltip, I get a gray/transparent background that I don't want. I Have tried remove padding or some of the background properties within bootstrap and the override of my css with no success.

```
.tooltip
{
    width:200px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -85px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;

    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;

    -webkit-transition-property:opacity, margin-top, visibility, margin-left;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.4s, 0.3s, 0.4s, 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

    -moz-transition-property:opacity, margin-top, visibility, margin-left;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.4s, 0.3s, 0.4s, 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

    -o-transition-property:opacity, margin-top, visibility, margin-left;
    -o-transition-duration:0.4s, 0.3s, 0.4s, 0.3s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;

    transition-property:opacity, margin-top, visibility, margin-left;
    transition-duration:0.4s, 0.3s, 0.4s, 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
}
/*a.tooltip > span:hover,*/
.tooltip.in
{
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration:none;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-top:20px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

tooltip.top{

    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: -19px;

    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;

    display: none;
}

.tooltip-inner  {
    color: #FFFFFF;

    background: #0033CC;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0033CC 0%, #0099FF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0033CC), color-stop(100%,#0099FF));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0033CC', endColorstr='#0099FF',GradientType=0 );

    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.tooltip-top {
    background: #0033CC;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Here is a [Working Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/EHapk/1/).
Notice that in the css, the tooltip properties are at the end, bootstrap.js and css are linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `box-shadow` property in bootstrap is making this issue. You can override it by adding the below code to your custom CSS.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/EHapk/5/)**

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: It sounds right, tried removing it before and it didn't work, now changed it with your setting, also, no success.
*I setup what you said on fiddle, and it works.. umm on project it doesn't. weird, same code

Comment: @user3086644 Did you check the demo?

Comment: Surjith SM, I see the demo working, edit once, copied twice.. not working in project, it's all the same!

Comment: @user3086644 If its working fine on demo, Then its mistake on implementing. Can you give me your link?

Comment: I can give you whatever you like, but by link you mean? a zip file with project inside?

Comment: OK, Try adding `!important` before each attribute like `box-shadow: none!important;`

Comment: Didn't help, The wierdest thing is that, there no gray property where ever you look for under .tooltip , so how can it be still gray!?

Comment: @user3086644 Please upload it in a server and give me the link. I will check it from here. I don't know what's going on there without seeing it.

Comment: @user3086644 OK, Got your file, I opened style.css, scrolled to very bottom, changed box-shadow: none; and saved. Working Fine.

Comment: First of all, really really appriciated.
Now on the small site I sent you, it works perfect.
I have no clue why, but when I replace the style.css file on the complete project, it still gives the same issue.
You have done more then enough, I will try to figure out later what causes this, probably some other css file is disturbing! big big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the bootstrap css with yours like this

instead of bootstrap css write this

```
.tooltip
 {
  box-shadow:none;
  border:none;
  background-color:transparent;
 }
```

for complete tutorial custom tooltip tutorial visit here http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-simple-tooltip-using-css3.php